# How to connect IKS environment using external Rundeck?

Tags: ibm-cloud, iks

I'm using external Rundeck present outside  IKS usually  we login to ibmcloud and then access IKS. But I need to access IKS environment with service account (cert & token). Is that possible? 
if yes how I can store this kubeconfig temporarily without storing it in .kube/config

Answer (score 1):

Create a 'Service ID' and within the service id create an 'API Key'
- Login to the ibmcloud console and choose Manage > Access (IAM)
- Create a Service ID
- Add the Access polices, by clicking the associated panel and then add policies
- Choose the API keys panel and click on create

I do not know what you mean to 'store temporarily'. But then the script can login using this api key in your script and config kubectl:

ibmcloud login --aipkey 6JaR7NOTAREALKEYPc-E01i-mlwc7_8zd29foobar2NA -g yourgroup
ibmcloud ks cluster config --cluster yourcluster
kubectl ...

Comment: Hi Powell, Thanks for reply !!.. I want to restrict to few operation (like get po and restart pod) but access polices are very limited